# Analog clock rotate transform

Tags: c#, wpf, clock, rotatetransform

I have problem with rotate transform in my analog clock.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
    Ellipse teckaa = new Ellipse();
    teckaa.Height = 30;
    teckaa.Width = 30;
    teckaa.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    teckaa.Fill = Brushes.Black;
    canvas.Children.Add(teckaa);
    Canvas.SetTop(teckaa, 25);
    Canvas.SetLeft(teckaa, 215);
    RotateTransform otoceni = new RotateTransform(i*30, 230, 230);
    canvas.RenderTransform = otoceni;
}
```

I have this code for hour points, but this is moving only with one point. Is there any way how to change name of the ellipse in cycle for()?

Comment: Why bother with the Name?  Problems seems to be that you apply the Transform to the whole Canvas. All 12 points are on top of each other.

Comment: OK, you can post the solution as a self-answer.

Comment: I have less than 10 reputation, so I can't answer my own question. I have replaced only canvas with teckaa. -> teckaa.RenderTransform = otoceni;

Comment: OK, I didn't know there was a treshold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the Transform to the individual hour markers and not the the entire Canvas:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 12; i++)
{
    Ellipse teckaa = new Ellipse();
    teckaa.Height = 30;
    teckaa.Width = 30;
    teckaa.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    teckaa.Fill = Brushes.Black;
    canvas.Children.Add(teckaa);
    Canvas.SetTop(teckaa, 25);
    Canvas.SetLeft(teckaa, 215);
    RotateTransform otoceni = new RotateTransform(i*30, 230, 230);

    //canvas.RenderTransform = otoceni;
    teckaa.RenderTransform = otoceni;     
}
```

And see Petzold for a really cool [all XAML clock](http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2006/04/070132.html).